# How to change colour and position of geom_text for just one bar in a barplot in ggplot2 (R)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I'm trying to create a bar plot with the depicted values written inside the bars using ggplot2. I still want to label the group with value "0" but in a different colour (black) and just above the x-axis. How can I change the position and colour of just this one geom_text?

I've already tried entering a vector into scale_colour_manual but it didn't work (or I didn't do it right).

```
data <- read.table(text = "group percentage
               group1 30
               group2 29
               group3 0
               group4 18", header=TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=group, y=percentage))+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = "dodge", fill="#13449f")+
  geom_text(aes(label = percentage), position = position_dodge(0.9), 
  vjust=1.3, colour = "white", size=6)
```

With this code there is no label for group3 since there is no bar either. I'd like to still have a label in black above the x-axis.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! This is a very well formatted and clear first question, congratulations!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Via conditional logic:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x = group, y = percentage))+
    theme_bw()+
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = "dodge", fill = "#13449f") +
    geom_text(aes(label = percentage), position = position_dodge(0.9), 
              vjust = ifelse(data$percentage > 3, 1.3, -0.3), 
              colour = ifelse(data$percentage > 3, "white", "black"), 
              size = 6)
```

[image: 1]

With `group3 == 3.1`

[image: 2]

What is comfortable about this approach:

- it automatically takes care of values that are big and small
- you do not need a second data frame or geom

Caveat of this approach:

- What is hardcoded as `> 3` should be calibrated for each visualization. It **is possible** to automatize that part if you dive deeper into how ggplot2 builds graphs, but it would be overkill for this small example.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I've been looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Just add another geom_text layer. For example

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=group, y=percentage))+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = "dodge", fill="#13449f")+
  geom_text(aes(label = percentage), position = position_dodge(0.9), 
            vjust=1.3, colour = "white", size=6) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = "0", y=1), data=subset(data, percentage==0), size=6)
```

Here we change the layer data to only include those groups with 0s.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it could have been that easy...! But I have a similar problem where the bar is basically too "small" to contain the entire number (e.g. when the percentage is just 1 or 0.5). How can I then shift this single number above the bar and change its colour? Here your "trick" doesn't apply.